# When loading a script with $.getScript() is there a way to call a function in the parent script, from the script being loaded with $.getScript()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getscript

Say I have 'main.js', and in 'main.js' I use $.getScript() to load 'secondary.js'

'main.js' has a function inside of it called function runme().

Is there a way to call runme() from secondary.js?

Comment: Sure there is, if the function is in scope you just call it normally in the done callback for $.getScript

Comment: @adeneo I just set up a jsfiddle to show my code: jsfiddle.net/TyGoss/j9ddLhj3 After checkout.js loads, I use $.getScript() to load stripe.js I'm trying to call setup() from stripe.js, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

If `secondary.js` is being loaded from within `main.js`, then all the public  functions in `main.js` are already available to `secondary.js` so any code in `secondary.js` is free to call any public function in `main.js` at any time.

You will have to make sure that any functions from `main.js` that you want to call from `secondary.js` are truly public functions (accessible from the global scope in some way) and are not declared within some other function in `main.js`.

---

FYI, you have a strange mix of jQuery and plain JS that tries to sequence the loading of the two scripts.  I'd suggest you simplify that to this:

```
$.getScript("https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"), function() {
    $.getScript("stripe.js");
});
```

Comment: Alright i've updated my jsfiddle with more detailed information. My function is definitely global, so why can't my secondary script (stripe.js) call it?

http://jsfiddle.net/TyGoss/j9ddLhj3/1/

Comment: @TyGoss - It is callable if it's global so it is probably not actually global.  Is it defined within any other function such as within a `$(document).ready()` function?  You can make absolutely sure it's global by defining it as `window.setupPayment = function(token, plan) {...}`.  If `main.js` is also being loaded dynamically, then you will have to worry about which one is being loaded first.

Comment: @TyGoss: you kept the default settings which runs the code "on load". I.e the code is out in a callback and hence anything defined in there is not global. Know thy tools!

Comment: @jfriend00 It's not inside of any document.ready() or anything else.

I'm actually creating a Firefox Extension, and so my main.js is being loaded  by the extension, but my main.js is the only thing that's loading stripe.js, and my main.js file defines setupPayment before it loads stripe.js, so you'd think stripe.js would be able to call setupPayment, but it's still returning: "line 16: ReferenceError: setupPayment is not defined"

Comment: @FelixKling - that isn't runnable code in the jsFiddle (not the plain reference to "stripe.js").  I think that's just as a means of sharing code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I even changed it to window.setupPayment like you suggested, and it's still undefined.

Comment: @TyGoss - Then you have some sort of timing or scoping issue and we'd have to see the actual real code in it's real setting to have an idea how to advise you. Also, I don't know if the "global" space in a Firefox extension is the `window` object or not and functions declared in the extension may not automatically go into the global space.  Extensions might live in a slightly different world.  You should have included that bit of information in your original question.

Comment: @TyGoss - as I suspected, Firefox extensions don't define symbols in the "traditional" global namespace - they have their own namespace.  I haven't found the exact answer to your problem yet, but searches for `"global variable Firefox extension"` yield lots of discussion of the issues.

Comment: @TyGoss: there is no reason to create a JSFiddle if the code cannot be executed.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the simpler suggestion on including both checkout.js and stripe.js, I think we all appreciate simpler code.

So I did some testing, with Firefox extensions you have a pageMod function that includes content scripts, and I have my base.js file included as one of those content scripts, then that base.js file is using $.getScript() to include other files (due to the order things have to happen, and the base.js decides which other js files to load.) It looks like any file that's loaded via $.getScript can't access any functions in my base.js file.

Comment: @FelixKling how do I display code inside of the comments here?

Comment: @TyGoss: Just like you do it in questions, with backticks. There also is a help link under the `Add Comment` button which explains the styling options. However, longer code should be included in your question anyway, it's not readable in comments.

Comment: @TyGoss - you need to understand what namespace an extension is loaded into and what namespace dynamically loaded scripts from your extension are loaded into.  `base.js` is probably NOT in the global namespace which is probably why other scripts can't see functions it defines.  There is likely a mechanism by which you can either change how the script is loaded or by which you can "publish" shared functions that the other script can see.